# Windows 10 on Colorovo tablet - touch screen don't working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, touchscreen, tablet

A few days ago I deleted the recovery partition on my Colorovo CityTab 8 tablet. I don't know how to make a recovery from USB (there is an error in something connected with diskpart when I try) so decided to install Windows 10. Installation was fine. I had to use mouse and keyboard, but almost everything installed fine. Almost, because the touchscreen isn't working. I tried to update all of the drivers manually and with driver booster, but the touchscreen still doesn't work. The volume buttons also don't work. Did I install properly or do I have to use another version of the system?

Comment: I assume it didn't come with Windows 10? If there are not available drivers from Colorovo best stick with the version of Windows it came with.

Comment: but there is avaiable update to win 10 from win 8.1... In addiction i can say that, when i installed win 8.1 in that way like win 10, touch screen doesn't working too.

Comment: Just because Windows 10 does not mean there are device drivers that support it for your device.